# How to plot multiple graphs from the International Standard Atmosphere model in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

How do I plot a graph showing how pressure, speed of sound, density and temperature change based on altitude?

The International Standard Atmosphere model captures this but I need to do it in MATLAB.

Comment: what is the question? Can you provide more information?

Comment: Have you seen [`atmosisa`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/aerotbx/ug/atmosisa.html)?

Comment: Please provide some code or any other reference when asking a question next time.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a full example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Aerospace toolbox, this seems like a straightforward use of [`atmosisa`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/aerotbx/ug/atmosisa.html) and [`subplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html).

[image: Graphs showing Temperature, Speed of Sound, Pressure, and Density as a function of Height]

The relevant assumptions and measurement units are in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/aerotbx/ug/atmosisa.html).

```
% MATLAB R2019a
height = [0:1000:20000];            % meters
[T, a, P, rho] = atmosisa(height);

% Plot
figure
s(1) = subplot(2,2,1)
    plot(height,T)
    ylabel('Temperature (K)')
s(2) = subplot(2,2,2)
    plot(height,a)
    ylabel('Speed of Sound (m/s)')
s(3) = subplot(2,2,3)
    plot(height,P)
    ylabel('Pressure (Pa)')
s(4) = subplot(2,2,4)
    plot(height,rho)
    ylabel('Density (kg/m^3)')

% Cosmetics
for jj = 1:4
    xlabel(s(jj),'Height (m)')      % Common label for x-axis

    ax = s(jj);
    ax.XRuler.Exponent = 0;         % Remove scientific notation 
    ax.YRuler.Exponent = 0;
end
```